# Quiero insertar todos los parámetros por teclado, de forma dinámica aplicando herencia, clases abstractas y polimorfismo

Tags: java, poo, herencia, polimorfismo

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehiculos vehiculoCarga = new transCarga("AAA-000", "Mateo Contreras", "TOYOTA", 2011, "Gris", "ACPM", 1200, 500);
        
        Vehiculos[] vehiculo = new Vehiculos[1];
        
        vehiculo[0] = vehiculoCarga;
        
        System.out.println("\nVehiculos de forma porlimorfica");
        
        for (Vehiculos vehiculoActual : vehiculo){
           System.out.println(vehiculoActual); // invoca a toString
           
           System.out.println("ingresos "+ vehiculoActual.Costo());
        }
    }  
}

public abstract class Vehiculos {
    protected String placa;
    protected String color; 
    protected String marca;
    protected String nombPropietario; 
    protected String tipoCombustible;
    protected int modelo;
    
    public Vehiculos(){
        this.placa = " ";
        this.color = " ";
        this.marca = " ";
        this.nombPropietario = " ";
        this.tipoCombustible = " ";
        this.modelo = 1;
    }

    Vehiculos(String placa, String propietario, String marca, int modelo, String color, String combustible) {
        this.placa = placa;
        this.color = color;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.nombPropietario = propietario;
        this.tipoCombustible = combustible;
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public String getPlaca() {
        return placa;
    }

    public void setPlaca(String placa) {
        this.placa = placa;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    public String getNombPropietario() {
        return nombPropietario;
    }

    public void setNombPropietario(String nombPropietario) {
        this.nombPropietario = nombPropietario;
    }

    public String getTipoCombustible() {
        return tipoCombustible;
    }

    public void setTipoCombustible(String tipoCombustible) {
        this.tipoCombustible = tipoCombustible;
    }

    public int getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(int modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nPropietario: "+getNombPropietario()+"\nPlaca: "+getPlaca()+"\nMarca: "+getMarca()+"\nModelo: "
                    +getModelo()+"\nColor: "+getColor()+"\nTipo de Combustible: "+getTipoCombustible();
    }
    public abstract double Costo();
}

public class transCarga extends Vehiculos{
    private double precioKm;
    private double Km;
    
    public transCarga(String placa, String propietario, String marca, int modelo, 
                        String color, String combustible, double precioKm, double Km){
        super(placa, propietario, marca, modelo, color, combustible);
        setPrecioKm(precioKm);
        setKm(Km);
    }
    public void setPrecioKm(double precioKm){
        if (precioKm < 0){ // valida el precio de lo que equivale 1Km
            this.precioKm=0;
        }
        else
            this.precioKm = precioKm;
    }
    public double getPrecioKm(){
        return precioKm;
    }
    
    public void setKm(double Km){
        if (Km < 0){ // valida los Km recorridos
            this.Km = 0;
        }
        else
            this.Km = Km;
    }
    public double getKm(){
        return Km;
    }

    @Override
    public double Costo() {
        if (getKm()<400) // no excede los 400Km
            return getPrecioKm() * getKm();
        else
            return getPrecioKm() * getKm() + (getPrecioKm()* getKm() * 0.05);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "\nVehículo de Carga: "+super.toString()
               +"\nKm recorridos: "+getKm()
                +"\nPrecio equivalente a 1Km:"+getPrecioKm();
    }
```

¿Alguien me podría asesorar en como puedo poner este código de forma dinámica? He intentado pero no he podido. No estoy pidiendo que me lo hagan, solo que me asesoren.

Inicialmente aplico clases abstractas y polimorfismo pero me gustaría que todos esos datos se pudieran ingresar de forma dinámica. Yo tengo la idea aplicando herencia y junto con los otros dos componentes que nombre anteriormente, pero a la hora de implementar el código no me da y me gustaría resolver mi duda. No tengo a nadie que me pueda asesorar.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres cuando dices dinámicamente? ¿Pedir al usuario que ingrese los datos por teclado?

Comment: Si, a eso me refiero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es declarar `variables` para cada dato que necesitas leer, también un arreglo de `objetos` de la clase `TransCarga` y un objeto de la clase `TransCarga` para ir guardando los datos de cada objeto.
Te dejo el código de la clase `Principal`, el resto de tu código está bien

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<TransCarga> listaTransCargas= new ArrayList<>();
        Vehiculos vehiculoCarga;
        
        String continuar;
        boolean flag=true;
        
        String placa;
        String color; 
        String marca;
        String nombPropietario; 
        String tipoCombustible;        
        int modelo;
        double precioKm;
        double km;
        
        while(flag){
            System.out.println("Ingrese placa: ");
            placa=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese color: ");
            color=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese marca: ");
            marca=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese nombre de propietario: ");
            nombPropietario=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese tipo de combustible: ");
            tipoCombustible=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese modelo: ");
            modelo=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese precio KM: ");
            precioKm=sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Ingrese km: ");
            km=sc.nextDouble();
            sc.nextLine();          
            
            //Instanciar un nuevo objeto de la clase TransCarga
            vehiculoCarga= new TransCarga(placa, nombPropietario, marca, modelo, color, tipoCombustible, precioKm, km);
            listaTransCargas.add((TransCarga) vehiculoCarga);
            System.out.println("Desea Ingresar Otro Dato?");
            continuar=sc.nextLine();
            if(!"S".equals(continuar)&!"s".equals(continuar))flag=false;
        }        
        
        System.out.println("\nVehiculos de forma porlimorfica");
        
        for (Vehiculos vehiculoActual : listaTransCargas){
           System.out.println(vehiculoActual); // invoca a toString
           
           System.out.println("ingresos "+ vehiculoActual.Costo());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo.